# How to use my Belkin Router as a Range Extender

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, bridge, repeater

I have a Binatone Modem+Router 2-in-1 which provides my main internet connection. It has an IP Address of 192.168.1.1 and I wish to extend its network coverage to a larger area, by using my old Belkin Wireless Router (Model No:F7D1301 v1). This old router has an IP Address of 192.168.2.1. How can I achieve this? I want the old router to basically harness the Wi-Fi signals from the main router and re-cast them further. It doesn't matter to me whether they both have the same SSID and Password or they are different.

Comment: Change the address Belkin  so it exists on the same network as the Binatone.  In other words change the address from `192.168.2.1` to `192.168.1.2`  If you can't change the address then you cannot extend the network created by the Binatone.

Comment: The factory firmware does not allow for this to be a repeater or WiFi client, you must flash the router with DD-WRT or OpenWRT and set it up as a repeater. https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge